# Hidden checkbox fields HTML

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to create hidden checkbox fields and when user click on field it will be checked.

Here is my example..

http://jsfiddle.net/NnQvD/

```
<h3>Choose color</h3>

<ul class="color-picker list-inline">
    <li class="active"><a class="active gray" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="yellow" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="red" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="green" href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

+CSS (Look on jsfiddel)

Now i want to put hidden checkbox in that color blocks.

Comment: that is a bad idea. why need to hide? Whatever you are trying to do, there is a better solution instead of using hidden checkbox

Comment: Well I don't know.. I thought it was a good idea. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: do you allow multiple selected color?

Comment: Yes, user can select all color if he want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your markup, using a form. Javascript is not necessary (unless you need to support IE8 or older browser)

Example code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ixira

Every checkbox covers its label and it's transparent: so when you click a colour you're actually clicking the checkbox. The different style for the selected colour is applied through the `:checked` pseudoclass.

Markup

```
<form>
  <fieldset>

     <ul>
       <li>
         <input type="checkbox" name="y" />
         <label>Gray</label>
       </li>    
       <li>
         <input type="checkbox" name="r" />
         <label>Red</label>
       </li>    
       <li>
         <input type="checkbox" name="g" />
         <label>Green</label>
       </li>    
       <li>
         <input type="checkbox" name="b" />
         <label>Blue</label>
       </li>            
     </ul>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li { 
  position: relative;   
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .01;
  cursor: pointer;
}


label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  text-indent: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

[name="y"] + label { background: gray; }
[name="r"] + label { background: red; }
[name="g"] + label { background: green; }
[name="b"] + label { background: blue; }

input:checked + label { 
  border: 5px #fff double; 
}
```

---

Note: You could also obtain the same behaviour if you `display: none` your checkboxes and use a `for` attribute on labels (in that case also use a `cursor: pointer` on labels for better usability) — here an example of this approach: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGBvq

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your code to:

```
<ul class="color-picker list-inline">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gray">
        <label for="gray" class="gray"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yellow">
        <label for="yellow" class="yellow"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="red">
        <label for="red" class="red"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="green">
        <label for="green" class="green"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are just a few changes I did. To make it looking good you may need to invest some more time to it.

```
.color-picker li {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width:40px;
            height:50px;
        }
        .color-picker label {
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .color-picker .gray {
            background-color: gray;
        }
        .color-picker .yellow {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .color-picker .red {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .color-picker .green {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .color-picker input[type='checkbox'] {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .color-picker label {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
        }

        .color-picker input:checked + label {
            border-color: black;
        }
```

Your changed Demo: fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ is an example how you can hide your checkboxes and replace them with graphics

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one colour you want selecting you can use a radio button instead which would be a better idea than a checkbox.

Make sure you have a label doing most of the work.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

input {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a fiddle that uses a label for selecting the boxes.  You may have to display the radio buttons in IE as selecting with a label doesn't always work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5T4J/1/